# Order of elements become wrong after rendering erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a wired problem when developing rails. The order of elements in container is

```
 <div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
  <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
 </div>
```

For most of the pages, it works well. But it goes wrong when it renders following page

```
<% provide(:title, 'All Apps') %>
<h1>All Apps</h1>
<table class="apps table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>App Name</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <%= render @apps %>
    </tbody>
</talbe>
```

The order of elements in container becomes

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>All Apps</h1>
    <footer class="footer">...</footer>
    <pre class="debug_dump">...</pre>
    <table class="app table">...</table>
</div>
```

What confuses me is that only this page goes wrong. I am using Rails 4.0.5.

Comment: What `order` are you expecting?

Comment: @Pavan in .erb, footer is under <%= yield%>. After rendering, the <%=yield%>,whose content is <table class="app table">, becomes the last element in container.

Comment: have you literally copy/pasted the code or have you typed it in? if copy/paste... `</talbe>` otherwise - I'd look for a simple unclosed div or other tag.

Comment: @TarynEast thanks, </talbe> causes the problem. Browser automatically  completes the <table> tag and ignores </talbe> tag, which makes it hard to find the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is most probably happening is your browser HTML parser is trying to fix things, by putting elements "floating" in a table (without being in a `tr>td`) before the table. You probably have an unclosed tag.

(which is why it's vering important in cases like these to check the generated html and compare it to the browser's DOM panel - it can be very different !)